# Struggling to pronounce words ending with "sts"

Tags: pronunciation

When it comes to plural words ending with "sts" (e.g. "Scientists", "Atheists", "Priests"), It becomes very difficult for me to pronounce the "sts" part, it's like if my tongue gets stuck there and even when I try to do my best to pronounce this kind of words, it does not sound natural at all (However, I can easily pronounce the singular form of these words). Any tips that can help me? I always try to go for an american accent, since it seems the easiest for me to speak.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really bother trying to articulate the /t/ myself - I just slightly exaggerate the /s/ because I'm effectively "repeating" it. I doubt anyone normally notices though - they hear what they expect, and they expect a /t/ there. For example, many Anglophones think they can hear a /t/ in ***prints*** that's not present in ***prince***, despite the fact that almost no-one can or does *articulate* any such difference.

Comment: ...for the *singular*, I'll articulate the /t/ in *a **scientist at** Yale* because it's followed by a vowel, but not in *a **scientist working** on the project* (where again, it's just a slightly exaggerated /s/, identical to the plural form).

Comment: @FumbleFingers So would saying "Scientiss" do the job for you? Also can you give more details on how exactly do you exaggerate the /s/?

Comment: @AmirWG  How would you say the words, "a scientist says"? If you practice that, with a pause between "scientist" and "says", you'll have the same sequence of consonants as in plural "scientists". Then you can practice it faster, until the gap is gone and it's still all pronounced.

Comment: The 't' in such as prints [vs prince] is almost a front-of-tongue equivalent of a glottal stop, there's a slight stall but no completely grinding to a halt to enunciate it . No, I wouldn't know the name of such a device, but there is a clear distinction in how that affects the pronunciation of each. I imagine once we're asked to enunciate one after the other just to see how we do it, the distinction becomes more emphasised, but I'd claim it is there already.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty - good idea. I recall something similar with the Formula 1 driver, Kvyatt. I can say it, with no training in Russian, but many of the commentators never got past calling him *'caveat'* even with the emphasis on their added 'a'.

Comment: In normal conversational contexts, I might be inclined to *think* I'm saying things slightly differently, but in reality there's probably no detectable difference between me saying *The **scientist** said XYZ* and *The **scientists** said XYZ.* I don't have access to the stats, but I bet well under half of all native Anglophones in the UK enunciate the first /d/ in ***Wednesday*** at all (and a far smaller proportion of us would actually *notice* whether someone else pronounces it the same way we do, with or without that extra /d/).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I think Wednesday is different. I don't think most people would even consider the 'd' ought to be pronounced at all; effectively silent. 'scientists said' is getting into tongue-twister territory, where it will just tend to get merged, any last hint of a 't' being ducked to avoid the huge set of esses on the horizon resulting in a catastrophic fall ;)

Comment: @DoneWithThis: Different people will have different ideas about what they think is a tongue-twister. But the more important point is that *people hear what they expect*. Hence many people who know perfectly well how to pronounce ***nuclear*** don't even notice when others clearly articulate the increasingly common form "**nucular**" (and I'd hardly say either of those are particularly "difficult"). Anyway, my guess is 10-20% of UK Anglophones articulate two /d/'s in Wednesday at least *sometimes* - but I never do, and would very rarely notice whether someone else does or not.

Comment: "nucular" is a pet hate of mine - I can spot it from 200 yards in a strong headwind ;) Like vis, vat & ven & fink. [George Russell, are you listening?]